How do you put a usable brake on a bike trailer?
How are you able to brake when on a bike trailer? I am making a bike trailer and need some tips on how to make it.

I've tried to make your title clearer. If it doesn't say what you meant, feel free to say so and I'll change it back, or you can also undo the edit.

Is the biker intended to be in control of the braking? If I were towing someone who could brake independently, I think I'd crash for sure.

Is your intent to slow the trailer while riding or a parking brake to prevent rolling while parked or dismounting?

Similar question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18440/does-anyone-sell-bicycle-trailers-with-brakes

I've never needed a brake on my bike trailer. I have a Thule Chariot and my cargo is my kids. My bicycle brakes do just fine, although I burn through pads faster and I keep the braking in top shape as I'm able.

@timmy Is your question actually, "How do you apply braking to trailer wheels when you're towing a trailer?"
